# Removing default value "Please seleact a value..." from dropdown of nintex forms

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I'm facing this issue where I've five dropdowns on my form made with nintex forms. Three existing dropdowns work fine but the two new dropdown displays the option "Please select a value..." as the default option even though the default value I've set is "Select Action". Does anybody has any idea why this is happening?

Full details:
All dropdowns are connected to respective choice type fields in the sharepoint list.
All dropdowns have unique names as well as unique javascript variable.
I've tried setting default values in sharepoint list as well as in the form but no luck.

The list column has three choices:

1. Select Action (default)
2. Final
3. In-Progress

The form displays it like:

1) Please select a value... (default)

2) Select Action

3) Final

4) In-Progress

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? and how to resolve it? I don't want the default nintex value - "Please select a value..." as it doesn't look too professional.

Update:
This behaviour by form is for already existing items. For new items, the default is working fine. But I've lots of old items in list which cannot be discarded.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on drop down control and under settings -> Set default value  source  -> specify default value.

Second approach:

Under list setting ,click on the column name and specify the default value

Comment: I've tried both of these methods but it is not working.

Comment: @Griph can you check under option button setting under appearance whether Use custom "Please select" text is set to No.